# glibcxx_3.4.20 not found

Tags: clang, llvm

I'm using Ubuntu 14.04, after installing LLVM & Clang, when i tap this in the terminal it reports the error:

```
wishfay@wishfay-virtual-machine:~$ clang -v
clang: /usr/lib/x86_64-linux-gnu/libstdc++.so.6: version `GLIBCXX_3.4.20' not found (required by clang)
```

And i check my libstdc++.so.6:

```
wishfay@wishfay-virtual-machine:~$ locate libstdc++.so.6
/usr/lib/vmware-tools/lib32/libstdc++.so.6
/usr/lib/vmware-tools/lib32/libstdc++.so.6/libstdc++.so.6
/usr/lib/vmware-tools/lib64/libstdc++.so.6
/usr/lib/vmware-tools/lib64/libstdc++.so.6/libstdc++.so.6
/usr/lib/x86_64-linux-gnu/libstdc++.so.6
/usr/lib/x86_64-linux-gnu/libstdc++.so.6.0.19
/usr/share/gdb/auto-load/usr/lib/x86_64-linux-gnu/libstdc++.so.6.0.19-gdb.py
```

And my gcc version:

```
wishfay@wishfay-virtual-machine:~$ gcc --version
gcc (Ubuntu 4.8.4-2ubuntu1~14.04.3) 4.8.4
```

And libstdc++.so.6:

```
wishfay@wishfay-virtual-machine:~$ strings /usr/lib/x86_64-linux-gnu/libstdc++.so.6 | grep GLIBCXX
GLIBCXX_3.4
GLIBCXX_3.4.1
GLIBCXX_3.4.2
GLIBCXX_3.4.3
GLIBCXX_3.4.4
GLIBCXX_3.4.5
GLIBCXX_3.4.6
GLIBCXX_3.4.7
GLIBCXX_3.4.8
GLIBCXX_3.4.9
GLIBCXX_3.4.10
GLIBCXX_3.4.11
GLIBCXX_3.4.12
GLIBCXX_3.4.13
GLIBCXX_3.4.14
GLIBCXX_3.4.15
GLIBCXX_3.4.16
GLIBCXX_3.4.17
GLIBCXX_3.4.18
GLIBCXX_3.4.19
GLIBCXX_DEBUG_MESSAGE_LENGTH
```

I want to know how can i get the GLIBCXX_3.4.20 .

Comment: In addition, I'm using Ubuntu 14.04.

Comment: Rather than adding this detail in a comment, you should edit your question

Answer (score 0, accepted):

According to the [ABI page](https://gcc.gnu.org/onlinedocs/libstdc++/manual/abi.html), `GLIBCXX_3.4.20` is part of `gcc-4.9`.

You need to upgrade your version of `gcc`, or get a `clang` binary that supports your OS, or you need to build `clang` from source.

Comment: I tried to update my gcc to version 4.9 and it really works! Thank you very much!